# circuit analysis of a PIR circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

While I have a good idea how this circuit works, there are few doubts.

1, what is the purpose of R1(10K), R2 (18k) and C102 (47u)?

2, Also I notice that few of these PIR modules have an input diode, other than the obvious polarity protection, is there any important purpose for D1?

[image]

Comment: What is the PIR sensor?

Answer (score 1):

The resistors and cap work like a filter or bias voltage for the PIR sensor used in that module. Note that the BIS0001 (generic PIR sensor IC) does not require it, and many modules don't have it. It really depends on how good the sensor is.

The diode is just for reverse voltage input protection. It also drops the input voltage by ~0.7 volts, so the regulator drops less as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not just any filter but R1C102 has T=470 ms which gives 20dB noise rejection at T=47ms transient noise which is critical as this is in the bandwidth and slew rate of motion. (4Hz)

Comment: That is interesting, but what is the name to that filter? and how does it work? This is probably the key to my own PIR circuit being too sensitive question that I posted few days ago without an answer yet.